# VBA memory size of Arrays and Arraylist

Tags: arrays, vba, memory, arraylist

I have tried to load 6.000.000 (6 mio) strings of 64 characters in length in order to sort them in VBA.
What I have noticed is :
1. When I use an Array the memory occupied is around 916 MB
2. When I use an ArrayList the memory occupied goes to 1.105 MB
None of them is reasonable to me as the strings size is around 380 MB.
What I doing wrong ?
As the numbers of strings will grow rapidly I will face 'Out of memory' very soon.
Any idea will be welcome.

Demetres

Comment: VBA doesn't have `ArrayList` - are you talking about VB.NET ?

Comment: I am developing in VBA in Excel. The statement that I use is:    'Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")'
It was 'Dim AL As Object' declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the issue is the fact that VBA natively uses [BSTRs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which are Unicode strings. I assume that your calculation of ~380 mb is based on 6 million * 64 characters @ 1 byte each.   In actuality, the math works out to something like this:

- VBA Strings are Unicode, which in this case means each character is 2
  bytes.
- A String in VBA is 4 bytes for internally storing the length before
  the string, 2 bytes for a unicode Null at the end of the string, and
  the 2 bytes per character.
- That works out to 4 + (64 * 2) + 2 = 134 bytes per 64 character
  String.
- Each entry in the String array is actually a pointer to the String,
  so that's another 4 bytes per slot, 138 in total so far.
- Assuming 6 million of these Strings, that's 828,000,000 bytes (using 
  commas US style) which, [depending upon your definition of mb](http://www.whatsabyte.com/), is either 789.6 or 828 mb.

I'm not sure about the rest of the overhead, perhaps garbage collector reference counters?

Anyway, I would suggest that you use 64 slot Byte arrays to load and store your strings, assuming it's ASCII characters.  You eliminate (4 + 64 + 2) * 6,000,000 bytes and your code will presumably run faster because it doesn't need to compare as many bytes.  You could probably optimize your sort by comparing a Word (32 or 64 bits depending upon your processor) at a time instead of just character by character.

**Update**

I think I was slightly wrong on that calculation.  Byte Arrays are [SAFEARRAYs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which have quite a bit of overhead themselves, about 20 bytes.  So the savings would be closer to (4 + 64 + 2 - 20) * 6,000,000.

---

## Raw ASCII String Sort Example

*Before you look at this example, please, **please** take my recommendation and import your text into Access to sort instead.  6 million strings for a total of 380 mb is well within [Access' limits](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx) and Access can (as I understand it) sort them without resorting to loading all the strings into memory at the same time*

Create a text file called "data.txt" with the following text:

```
This
Is
A
File
Of
Strings
To
Sort
```

In add a code module and call it "mdlQuickSort" and add the following code.  I haven't commented much, but if you're curious as to how it works you can read [Wikipedia's article on QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or let me know and I'll add better comments.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub QuickSortInPlace(ByRef arrArray() As Variant)
    If UBound(arrArray) <= 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    qSort arrArray, 0, UBound(arrArray)
End Sub

Private Sub qSort(ByRef arrArray() As Variant, left As Long, right As Long)
    Dim pivot As Long
    Dim newPivotIndex As Long
    If left < right Then
        pivot = MedianOf3(arrArray, left, right)
        newPivotIndex = partition(arrArray, left, right, pivot)
        qSort arrArray, left, newPivotIndex - 1
        qSort arrArray, newPivotIndex + 1, right
    End If
End Sub

Private Function partition(ByRef arrArray() As Variant, left As Long, right As Long, pivot As Long) As Long
    Dim pivotValue As Variant
    pivotValue = arrArray(pivot)
    Swap arrArray, pivot, right
    Dim storeIndex As Long
    storeIndex = left
    Dim i As Long
    For i = left To right - 1
        If CompareFunc(arrArray(i), pivotValue) = -1 Then
            Swap arrArray, i, storeIndex
            storeIndex = storeIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
    Swap arrArray, storeIndex, right
    partition = storeIndex
End Function

Private Sub Swap(ByRef arrArray() As Variant, indexA As Long, indexB As Long)
    Dim temp As Variant
    temp = arrArray(indexA)
    arrArray(indexA) = arrArray(indexB)
    arrArray(indexB) = temp
End Sub

Private Function MedianOf3(ByRef arrArray() As Variant, left As Long, right As Long) As Long
    Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, c As Variant
    Dim indexA As Long, indexB As Long, indexC As Long
    Dim ab As Long
    Dim bc As Long
    Dim ac As Long
    indexA = left
    indexB = (left + right) \ 2
    indexC = right
    a = arrArray(indexA)
    b = arrArray(indexB)
    c = arrArray(indexC)

    ab = CompareFunc(a, b)
    bc = CompareFunc(b, c)
    ac = CompareFunc(a, c)

    If ab = -1 Then
        If ac = -1 Then
            If bc = -1 Or bc = 0 Then
                'a b c
                'Already in B
            Else
                'a c b
                Swap arrArray, indexB, indexC
            End If
        Else
            'c a b
            Swap arrArray, indexA, indexB
        End If
    Else
        If bc = -1 Then
            If ac = -1 Then
                'b a c
                Swap arrArray, indexA, indexB
            Else
                'b c a
                Swap arrArray, indexB, indexC
            End If
        Else
            'c b a
            'Already in B
        End If
    End If
    MedianOf3 = indexB
End Function

Private Function CompareFunc(str_a As Variant, str_b As Variant) As Long
    Dim a As Byte
    Dim b As Byte
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 63
        a = str_a(i)
        b = str_b(i)
        If a <> b Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If i <= 63 Then
        If a < b Then
            CompareFunc = -1
        Else
            CompareFunc = 1
        End If
    Else
        CompareFunc = 0
    End If

End Function
```

Finally, add a module called "mdlMain".  This is where the Strings are loaded.  Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Main()
    Dim arrStrings() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'Get the strings from the file
    FillArrStringsInPlace arrStrings

    'Print the unsorted list
    Debug.Print "Unsorted Strings" & vbCrLf & "---------------------"
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrStrings)
        Debug.Print StrConv(arrStrings(i), vbUnicode)
    Next

    'Sort in place
    QuickSortInPlace arrStrings

    'Print the sorted list
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Sorted Strings" & vbCrLf & "---------------------"
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrStrings)
        Debug.Print StrConv(arrStrings(i), vbUnicode)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub FillArrStringsInPlace(ByRef arr() As Variant)
    Dim iFile As Integer
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim lineCount As Long
    Dim arrBytes() As Byte

    'Open a file in the same folder as this Access db called "data.txt"
    iFile = FreeFile
    Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\data.txt" For Input As iFile

    'Since I already know how many strings there are, I'm assigning it here.
    'The alternatives would be to either "dynamically resize" the array, which
    'is equivalent to copying the entire thing everytime you add a new string,
    'Or to count the number of newlines in the file and dimensioning the array
    'to that size before reading in the strings line by line.  Neither is as
    'efficient as just defining it before-hand.
    ReDim arr(0 To 7)

    While Not EOF(iFile)
        Line Input #iFile, strInput
        arrBytes = StrConv(strInput, vbFromUnicode)
        ReDim Preserve arrBytes(0 To 63)
        arr(lineCount) = arrBytes
        lineCount = lineCount + 1
    Wend

    Close iFile
End Sub
```

I had put some code in there to try and optimize things with CopyMemory, but it was a tad dangerous, so I decided to leave it out.

Comment: Really an answer !!! Thanks a lot.
I will also give a try to your suggestion of using Byte arrays.

Comment: Blackhawk dear, the process you are suggesting is a little bit complex to me. If you can, give me any hint or links to see.

Comment: @user3092241 Where are you loading the strings from?  Is it an ascii text file?

Comment: Yes this is true. I load the strings from an ASCII file.

Comment: @user3092241 If the number of strings really is going to "grow rapidly" (and you are going to forge ahead with the VBA sort instead of Access), I suggest splitting the set of strings up into manageable chunks of about 100 mb each, sort each chunk individually, then finally [merge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) them back together.  That will prevent the Out of Memory errors from occurring since you never have more than a couple hundred mb in memory at any one time.

Comment: Dear Blackhawk, I was away from my PC. Thank you very much for your unbelievable support! Also, I will agree with your approach of using a DB instead of memory. I will try to inform you about my final implementation. Again, many thanks about all the information!

Comment: Dear Blackhawk, can you suggest an MS link concerning Dictionaries and their structure as you did with BSTR ? It will valuable for me.

Comment: @Demetres Unfortunately the Dictionary is a bit more complex and undocumented than BSTRs.  BSTR documentation exists because of marshaling/interop.  However, the Dictionary only has documentation on its interface, not its implementation.  However, it was written by Eric Lippert (who incidentally contributes on StackExchange from time to time) and you can find tidbits on his blog about it. If you can ask this as a new question, I can pull together some links for you and try to present a good explanation.  There isn't enough room in the comments here :( Who knows,Eric might give you an answer!

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658774/how-strings-are-stored-in-a-vba-dictionary-structure>

Comment: @Demetres there is a green check mark left-top corner of this answer :) check it

Comment: @mehow and Demetres, Thanks :)