# How Strings are stored in a VBA Dictionary structure?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

As I am currently playing with huge number of strings (have a look at another question: [VBA memory size of Arrays and Arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526324/vba-memory-size-of-arrays-and-arraylist)) I used a scripting dictionary just for the feature of the keyed access that it has.
Everything was looking fine except that it was some how slow in loading the strings and that it uses a lot of memory. For an example of 100,000 strings of 128 characters in length, the Task manager showed at the end of the sub approximately 295 MB and when setting Dictionary=Nothing a poor 12 MB was remaining in Excel. Even considering internal Unicode conversion of strings 128 * 2 * 100,000 gives 25.6 MB ! Can someone explain this big difference ?

Comment: Using Task Manager to accurately determine details of internal memory usage is not reliable. Having said that though, a dictionary could be implemented as some kind of hash table, so just working out how many bytes of data you have is probably not a useful comparison.

Comment: Dear Roger, in such big sizes some more MBs are not of any interest. Any way, if I choose to go to a solution with a hash table I am coming again to use Arrays with the same size problem because of Unicode representation. Imagine that these strings are hash codes (SHA512) of longer strings with sizes more than 2,500 chars

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is all the info I could find on the Scripting.Dictionary:

[According to Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/0001/01/01/132160.aspx), who wrote the Scripting.Dictionary, "the actual implementation of the generic dictionary is an extensible-hashing-with-chaining algorithm that re-hashes when the table gets too full." (It is clear from the context that he is referring to the Scripting.Dictionary)  Wikipedia's [article on Hash Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is a pretty good introduction to the concepts involved. ([Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=scripting.dictionary&beta=0&rn=Fabulous%20Adventures%20In%20Coding&rq=site%3ablogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/&ac=2) is a search of Eric's blog for the Scripting.Dictionary, he occasionally mentions it)

Basically, you can think of a Hash Table as a large array in memory.  Instead of storing your strings directly by an index, you must provide a key (usually a string).  The key gets "hashed", that is, a consistent set of algorithmic steps is applied to the key to crunch it down into a number between 0 and current max index in the Hash Table.  That number is used as the index to store your string into the hash table. Since the same set of steps is applied each time the key is hashed, it results in the same index each time, meaning if you are looking up a string by its key, there is no need to search through the array as your normally would.

The hash function (which is what converts a key to an index into the table) is designed to be as random as possible, but every once in a while two keys can crunch down to the *same* index - this is called a collision. This is handled by "chaining" the strings together in a linked list (or possibly a more searchable structure). So suppose you tried to look a string up in the Hash Table with a key.  The key is hashed, and you get an index.  Looking in the array at that index, it could be an empty slot if no string with that key was ever added, or it could be a linked list that contains one or more strings whose keys mapped to that index in the array.

The entire reason for going through the details above is to point out that a Hash Table must be larger than the number of things it will store to make it efficient (with some exceptions, see [Perfect Hash Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function)).  So much of the overhead you would see in a Hash Table are the empty parts of the array that have to be there to make the hash table efficient.

Additionally, resizing the Hash Table is an expensive operation because the all the existing strings have to be rehashed to new locations, so when the load factor of the Hash Table exceeds the predefined threshold and it gets resized, it might get doubled in size to avoid having to do so again soon.

The implementation of the structure that holds the chain of strings at each array position can also have a large impact on the overhead.

If I find anything else out, I'll add it here...

Comment: Great reply Blackhawk ! My question has been clarified and you gave me food for further thoughts. I will the question still open, just in case ...