# Searching, Sorting, Matching, within Dynamic Multidimensional Array - VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, sorting

Before I begin, I know all of this can be accomplished with a SQL query. Just take my word that currently building an active directory is in the works, but right now this is what i have:

An excel spreadsheet of about 30k rows with about 25 columns with a list of items, using the item # as the level 1 match. Let's call it the "master" sheet.

The item #'s, which are unique identifiers, may appear multiple times, i.e.:

Item # 10000 can appear multiple times in this sheet.

So I created a dynamic array, and inserted the entire master sheet into the array using

```
Sub Items()

Dim Items() As Variant

   Sheets("Master").Activate

   Items = Range("A3", "AL" & Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row)

End Sub
```

The user will be on another sheet within the workbook ("itemlist"), and will enter some items they need like this: [Item List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2L25.png)

I need all occurrences (whether it be a single or duplicate value) of each of the items in the "Master" to output to individual rows on another sheet.

I'm stuck how to achieve this in VBA. I'm finding it difficult to find examples of this.

Would i want to sort the array first to make finding the duplicates faster? Should I turn the user created list into a single dimensional array and try to find intersecting points with the 2d array? I'm not sure where to start after the creation of the "master" array.

The reason I'm using arrays instead of a bunch of index matching or iterative looping in the "Master" sheet is because the processing power/physical memory available will be inconsistent due to computing environment, so arrays seem to be the most efficient method to avoid some users taking several minutes for return values if it can process at all.

Comment: My advice is that you take a look at how to use Dictionaries.

Comment: You are right that array processing will be a lot faster than range processing. I am unable to view your image where I am, but I do recommend you apply all your processing to the data while it is still in the array then read it back into the range.

Comment: Yes i agree.I'm just unsure how to apply all my data processing in the array with VBA. Do you have any tips where to look?

Comment: Thank you Remi. I just peeked at dictionaries, It almost looks as if it can be used like a recordset in my faux database.

Comment: Unfortunately Remi, it looks as if Dictionaries can only contain unique values, where in my example I'll be retrieving duplicate item numbers.

Comment: You can use a Dictionary to store an array of row numbers against each Item#, or to store a range representing all of the rows for each Item#

Comment: I realize you talk about "a SQL query", but you should know that it's pretty straightforward to accomplish this task in Microsoft Access. I would estimate about 15 minutes to import the data, create a table for your search criteria, then build and run the query.  A VBA solution written for this would take MUCH longer to build and MUCH longer to run.

Comment: If you still want to do things with a raw array, I can assist, but you have to realize that there really aren't any built-in VBA functions for searching, sorting or "matching" arrays. Anything you want you'll have to roll yourself. Also consider that sorting in this case actually costs you. Comparing your 9 search items to each of the 30k items is 270k comparisons, whereas quicksorting the list is ~446k comparisons.

Comment: @Blackhawk, I was bundling access into the SQL query mention earlier. Currently no Access available yet, but it's all coming soon. So instead of quicksorting (and i'm assuming bubble and the others would be even slower), what would be the best way to grab those items through the array? I'm thinking what Tim Williams said might be a decent method. Any insights you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I did a bit more number crunching and found that the crossover point for efficiency of unsorted search vs sorted search (quicksort/binary search)  is about 15 search items. By the time you get to needing to search for 50 items, the raw unsorted search takes 3 times as many comparisons.

Comment: So it depends on your use case. For the example you gave of searching through 30k items once for 9 particular items, unsorted searching will be much faster, especially considering the cost in time of implementing quicksort/binary search. If you're going to be searching for larger numbers of things, or if you are going to be repeatedly searching the same dataset, sort first. In fact, if you're just pulling data out of the sheet, why not sort using Excel's built-in sort before pulling it into an array?

Comment: In case you want to play around with it, I posted an implementation of quicksort as part of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20528918/2832561) answer. Performance-wise, Quicksort is as fast as you're going to get unless you were able to use a hybrid sort maybe provided by C++ runtime COM objects or something similar.

Comment: @Blackhawk Thanks for your insight. It pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean 'may appear multiple times'?  It sounds like you need xto group and sum, as you would in a database (Access or SQL Server) or do some ranking and pick the highest/lowest element in the array.  Or, are you saying you want to copy/paste certain element in your array to a new sheet???

Let's say you want to copy items in column B, which have a value of 'x', and paste them into another sheet, well, just run the script below.

```
Sub CopyData10()
Dim Rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim rw As Long
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B10")
rw = 1
For Each cell In Rng
If LCase(cell.Value) = "x" Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rw, "A") = cell.Offset(0, -1)
rw = rw + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```